# styling Markdown in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, markdown, scullyio

I am using right now Angular and Scully
I want to add style to the  in markdown file in Angular. But I have no idea how to do it.
The img right now is too big.
Can someone give me advices?

Please take a look at those pictures below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element of your mardown file will be rendered to a corresponding valid html tag.
You can target these tags to style your rendered markdown pages.

For example :

```
# Title
<h1>Title</h1>
```

Here is how markdown is rendered : https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/

Comment: img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

Comment: I have try the code above but It does not work. And I am using right now scully.io too

Comment: The content from Blog, come a little bit later after page rendered. I do not know if that a problem is

Comment: i initialized an angular project with scully and it works for me. i added the stlye on the img inside the blog.component.css. I deployed it on netlify : https://musing-meitner-f710ae.netlify.app/blog/first-blog

Comment: I still dont know what is wrong with my project. Can you please show me what you have in the markdown file?